# Two different ways to simplify $\tan x \cos^2x/(\sin x-\sin^3x)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Simplify $\tan x \cos^2x/(\sin x-\sin^3x)$

I tried to turn all terms into $\sin$ and $\cos$ and I got $\sec x$ as the answer. Then I tried to changed the $\cos^2x$ into $1-\sin^2x$ and ended up with $\tan x/\cos x$. Why am I getting different answers?

Comment: $\frac{\tan x\cdot \cos^2x}{\sin x-\sin^3x}=\frac{\sin x\cdot\cos^2 x}{\cos x\cdot(\sin x-\sin^3x)}=\frac{\cos x}{1-\sin^2 x}=\frac{\cos x}{\cos^2x}=\frac{1}{\cos x}=\sec x$. No ambiguity here.

Comment: Can you show your work? Tan.cos^2 =sin.cos.  sin (1-sin^2) = sin cos^2 so I get sec.  Kal though I only did it in my head.  Don't know how you got the second answer. Probably an error but it's impossible for us to predict how you got an error if you don't show your work.

Comment: If you did it the second way you should arrive at $\frac{\tan x}{\sin x}$, which is $\sec x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your first way is right but your second way is wrong . In the second way you must stopped at $\frac{\tan{x}}{\sin{x}}=\sec{x}$